# Replace white space in string only when there are two or more white spaces

Tags: r, regex

I am working with strings in `R`. I have the next string:

```
x<-c("Alfa  Cactus   500   Bachelor degree  Star")
```

For example, in this string after the first word I have two spaces. After the second word I have three spaces. I am trying to replace only white spaces when there are two or more of them. In that case I would like to add `*` instead of white spaces. I am looking for a new string like this:

```
Alfa*Cactus*500*Bachelor degree*Star
```

In the case of `Bachelor degree` I only have one white space. Then, the replace must not be done. When I try this:

```
gsub(" +","*",x)
```

I got this:

```
Alfa*Cactus*500*Bachelor*degree*Star
```

But, It is not respected the fact that only one white space must not be replaced. I do not know how to adapt `gsub` to perform this change.

I hope you can help me with this. Thanks a lot of.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need two spaces.

```
gsub("  +","*",x)
[1] "Alfa*Cactus*500*Bachelor degree*Star"
```

Comment: Worked perfect!